# Glyphicon bootstrap doesn't work probably

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend, glyphicons, web-frontend

I'm working on bootstrap framework and have issue about glyphicon. I'm using bootstrap v3.3.6, and in HTML, I have this glyphicon

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="false"></span>
```

But it doesn't show the icon. I think it causes because of the version in bootstrap. So I try to put this line to project

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The icon will be shown but all the style in project will be override, too. All be broken...:(

Does anyone have experience about this issue? Please give me some advices. 
Thanks.

Comment: But it is showing for me even I use 3.3.6 version  -<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Yes. If we insert the link to the header, it will work but the customized css will be override by bootstrap style. Anyway, thank for your help ^^

Comment: Can you give reference your custom CSS then it will be help for me to trace the fact.

Comment: I tried to reproduce my issue to fiddle, but can't make the issue happens. I think it cause because of the conflicted css in project.
So I found another way to show the symbol, use the :after pseudo code. And it works fine :D

Answer (score 1):

It works if we use minimal html code like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Test</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="false"></span>
</body>
```

You can get the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0orbqw9L/

I think your problem maybe some of your inline/application styles conflicting with the bootstrap styles. Usually the best way to work with bootstrap is to include bootstrap.css first and then your application css file.

If you still dont want to tinker with your existing styles, you can probably add specific styles in your application css file which overrides your bootstrap styles or earlier defined application styles like:

```
.tag {
  font-family: Arial !important; //see the !important which helps you override styles
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried all of them but the icon still didn't show. I tried the other glyphicon: glyphicon-plus -> it works but glyphicon-menu-right :( The glyphicon with content value starts by number: "\002a", "\002b"...still work fine. Glyphicon with content value starts by letter: "\e001", "\e002"...failed.
I don't know why...

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: I tried to reproduce my issue to fiddle, but can't make the issue happens. I think it cause because of the config in project. So many people working on it, maybe it be conflicted.
So I found another way to show the symbol, use the :after pseudo code. And it works fine :D